# swipe gesture recognizer in another class

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a ViewController that is connected to a second view SecondViewController and I would like to switch from one to another with a UIGesture

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let svc = SecondViewController()
        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: svc, action: #selector(svc.swipeAction(swipe:)))
        leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    }
}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeAction(swipe:)))
        rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @objc func swipeAction(swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
    {
        print(swipe.direction.rawValue)
        switch swipe.direction.rawValue {

        case 1:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTheLeft", sender: self)
        case 2:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTheRight", sender: self)
        default:
            break
        }
    }

}
```

The code does not work, nothing happens and I have no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `svc` goes out of scope at the end of `viewDidLoad` and your instance of `SecondViewController` gets deallocated.

Make `svc` a property of `ViewController`. When you wish to display the second view controller, display the instance stored in the `svc` property.

Keep in mind that it makes little sense to setup another view controller as the handler for a gesture in the first view controller.

Answer (score 0):

the target of the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` should be `self` in both view controller, and implement `swipeAction` separately in both view controller.